# How to check Plugin is installed or not?

Tags: nopcommerce

I wrote a plugin and used it inside `nop.web` project. Now I want to control that, if plugin has been installed or not.

Please give me solution.

Comment: have you try to use IPluginFinder if you need to check on view page then try to use this, i hope this helps

Comment: try to use this code var _pluginFinder = Nop.Core.Infrastructure.EngineContext.Current.Resolve<Nop.Core.Plugins.IPluginFinder>();
var _pluginSettings = Nop.Core.Infrastructure.EngineContext.Current.Resolve<your plugin setting>();
if (_pluginFinder.GetPluginDescriptorBySystemName("plugin system name") == null

Comment: thank you vap your comment is right its work

Comment: Happy to help Enjoy :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var pluginFinder = Nop.Core.Infrastructure.EngineContext.Current.Resolve<IPluginFinder>();

            // check plugin is installed
            var pluginDescriptor = pluginFinder.GetPluginDescriptorBySystemName("Misc.pluginname");

            if (pluginDescriptor != null)
            {
               //Your code
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to compile it and deploy it to your server. Then activate it under the plugins section from the administrator section.

Comment: i want to check only that specific plugin installed or not